Title: Calculating the First Derivative with Respect to $\xi_j$ in a Mixture Model
Title: Calculating the First Derivative with Respect to $\xi_j$ in a Mixture Model
I'm currently reading the section on soft parameter sharing in Chapter 9 of Deep Learning by Christopher M. Bishop, and I'm trying to calculate the first derivative of a function with respect to a parameter $\xi_j$ in the context of a mixture model.
Define the total error function as:
$$
\tilde{E}(w) = E(w) + \lambda \Omega(w)
$$
where the regularization term $\Omega(w)$ is defined as:
$$
\Omega(w) = -\sum_{i=1}^{K} \ln \left( \sum_{j} \pi_j N(w_i \mid \mu_j, \sigma_j^2) \right).
$$
This regularization term has to enforce a mixed distribution onto the weights parameters; the notation $N(w_i \mid \mu_j, \sigma_j^2)$ indicates the normal density with mean $\mu_j$ and variance $\sigma_j^2$ evaluated at $w_i$.
To enforce the positivity of the parameters $\sigma_j^{2}$ during gradient descent, define:
$$
\sigma_j^2 = \exp(\xi_j).
$$
The derivative of $\tilde{E}$ with respect to $\xi_j$ is given by:
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde{E}}{\partial \xi_j} = \frac{\lambda}{2} \cdot \sum_j \gamma_j(w_i) \cdot \left(1 - \frac{(w_i - \mu_j)^2}{\sigma_j^2}\right)
$$
where
$$
\gamma_j(w_i) := \frac{\pi_j N(w_i \mid \mu_j, \sigma_j^2)}{ \sum_k \pi_k N(w_i \mid \mu_k, \sigma_k^2)}.
$$
Question:
Where does the first term come from? I keep obtaining just the term:
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde{E}}{\partial \xi_j} = -\frac{\lambda}{2} \cdot \sum_j \gamma_j(w_i) \cdot \frac{(w_i - \mu_j)^2}{\sigma_j^2}.
$$
Can someone help?

What is the form of $E(w)$?

The error function of the least square method depending only on the weights of the neural network $E(w) = \sum_n E_n(w)$ and $E_n = \frac{1}{2} \sum_k (y_{nk} - t_{nk})^2.$ Apparently it does not depend from $\sigma_j.$

you definitely forgot taking the innermost derivative though. Differentiating a Gaussian with respect to its variance should always yield a $\sigma^3$ term in the denominator. In this case there should be a -$\xi_j$ term somewhere.
